# Oracle REST Handler Split Payload

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I've installed Oracle DB/ORDS and created all the handlers and related procedures by following Oracle-base guides. There is one issue which I was not able to solve, which seems simple but my lack of understanding SQL hinders me.

When I send JSON documents in bulk such as below;

```
{"tenantId":"wjg79702","userSessionId":"JAFLA....\n
{"tenantId":"wjg79702","userSessionId":"SLPW....\n
\n
```

This inserts all the records as expected. But I would like to insert every record one by one into individual CLOB columns. There is line break at the end of every record. How can I split them by incorporating additional functionality into my handler or procedure?

**Handler**

```
BEGIN
      create_kayit(p_kayit => :body_text);
END;
```

**Procedure**

```
create or replace PROCEDURE create_kayit (
p_kayit IN CLOB
)
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO uemtest (kayit) VALUES (p_kayit);
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        HTP.print(SQLERRM);
END;
```

**EDIT**
Solution has worked. I am sharing the final code for future refences.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE create_kayit (p_kayit IN CLOB) AS
BEGIN
        INSERT INTO UEMTEST (KAYIT)
        SELECT
        REGEXP_SUBSTR(p_kayit, '.+', 1, level, 'm') KAYIT
        FROM DUAL connect by level <= length(REGEXP_REPLACE(p_kayit,'.+'));
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        HTP.print(SQLERRM);
END;
```

Comment: are you storing json docs as clobs, in what version of oracle database? We have a simple oracle document access api (SODA) that makes this trivial - you POST your array of json, and we automatically create the documents for you https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2020/10/fastest-way-to-upload-a-bunch-of-documents-to-your-oracle-json-collection/

Comment: Yes I am storing them as CLOBS. Right now I am looking at how to go through the :body_text and use substring_regex to loop through these multiple records by carriage return and then insert them line by line. How can I define carriage return in substrin_regex function? I am using latest express edition of oracle, and standalone ORDS.

Comment: CLOBs will be less efficient to read back out, suggest you look at both SODA and BLOBS - faster, easier, way less code for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer your comment, if you want to do split by return carriage, one option might be `regexp_substr` and `connect by`

**Example**

```
SQL> select  regexp_substr(to_clob('line 1
  2  line 2
  3  line 3') , '.+',1,level,'m') from  dual
  4  connect by level <= regexp_count( to_clob('line 1
  5  line 2
  6* line 3'), '.+',1,'m')
  7  /

REGEXP_SUBSTR(TO_CLOB('LINE1LINE2LINE3'),'.+',1,LEVEL,'M')
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
line 1
line 2
line 3
```

You just need to incorporate this logic into your procedure.

Comment: Yes, your suggestion has worked. I wanted to share the final code for reference but I don't know how to do it in the comments section. Thank you very much.

Comment: @serhatbalik, you can always edit the question and post the code.